# Android ProgressDialog With AsyncTask Error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i have my AsyncTask, the only thing that this take care it's to show the list from a JSON Array usign Retrofit2. But because the data it's too extensive i decide to put a message while the app do the work.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public MyAsyncTask() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.sync));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        sincronizacionDB();
        Log.e("THREAD_BACKGROUND","SE HA REALIZADO INSERCION DE: " + sqLiteHandler.getLastIdBeneficio());
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        Log.e("THREAD","SE HA REALIZADO INSERCION DE: " + sqLiteHandler.getLastIdBeneficio());
        openAll();
    }

    private void openAll(){
        ListadoFragment listadoFragment = new ListadoFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContainer, listadoFragment).commit();
    }

    private void sincronizacionDB(){
        if(dbCheck(MainActivity.this,"beneficiosColaborador.db")){

        }else{
            Call<List<Beneficios>> callBeneficios = restManager.getApiService().getListadoBeneficios();
            callBeneficios.enqueue(new Callback<List<Beneficios>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Beneficios>> call, Response<List<Beneficios>> response) {
                    List<Beneficios> beneficioData = response.body();
                    for(Beneficios b : beneficioData){
                        Log.e("beneficio",b.getIdBeneficio() + " " + b.getNombreBeneficio());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Beneficios>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

CommonMethod commonMethod = new CommonMethod();
SQLiteHandler sqLiteHandler = new SQLiteHandler(this);
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private Spinner spinner;
private RestManager restManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    commonMethod.setActivity(this);
    commonMethod.setTaskBarColored(R.color.smooth_material_red);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_nav);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    Log.e("Finalido","ASYNC HA FINALIZADO");
```

But after many tries i can't figure out the reason behind this error.

ERROR LOG

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.freelance.crdzbird_dev.clarobadge.UI.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{145dc7ae V.E..... R......D 0,0-480,174} that was originally added here
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
                                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                                                      at com.freelance.crdzbird_dev.clarobadge.UI.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:238)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
                                                                                      at com.freelance.crdzbird_dev.clarobadge.UI.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

The Locations are on **DO IN BACKGOUND** and when i call **pDialog.show()**

Comment: Dismiss your dialog in onStop/onPause and recreate it when it's needed, you have a window leak

Comment: The error comes that doesn't even execute the ProgressDialog.show() :(

Comment: But you do, since onPreExecute occurs before doInBackground, and that's where you are showing your dialog. If I understand your comment, you got this error outside the doInBackground?